# Removing border when the form field is in focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am making the border appear for form field during form validation. I am appending error class name div class name to achieve it:

```
document.getElementById("name").className = document.getElementById("name").className + " error"; 
document.getElementById("email").className = document.getElementById("email").className + " error";  


&.error {
    border:3px solid #cc4337;
    transition:#cc4337 .2s linear 0;
    -webkit-transition:#cc4337 .2s linear 0;
    -moz-transition:#cc4337 .2s linear 0;
}
```

Now, when I click onto the form field to retype I want the border to disappear. Is there a way I can remove error (or style as border:none) from the class name by tracking what field is focused?

Thanks

Comment: use `.error:focus` selector to add another rule

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
&.error:focus{
  border: none;
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

or  also you could try

document.getElementById(id).style.property=new style

eg.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("error").style.border-color = "transparent";
</script>
```

and possibly implement using something like

```
 <input type="text" id="fname" onfocus="myFunction(this.id)">
```

Comment: I tried it. It makes the border disappear but the border re appears when I type in something in the field and move onto the next field. I wanted to make the border disappear permanently until next validation. I apologize for not being clear in my first post.

Comment: That didn't quite work. I am suspectign because it looks for ID "error" but I dont have a field by id error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the field to have its border removed temporarily, use the css selector `&.error:focus`. If you want to make it disappear permanently, you'll need to detect the focus using JavaScript and remove the class like this:

```
var foo = document.getElementById("email");
foo.className = foo.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)bar(?!\S)/ , '' );
```

By the way, you should declare the elements as variables this way, since your current implementation makes the code look for the element twice instead of once. :)

Comment: Thanks.! That is very a good suggestion :)

What does the regex in your snippet do? I wasn't able to figure that out.

Comment: It removes the class 'bar' from the element. The rest of the regex helps check if the class is somewhere in the class name when other classes are also applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
$('input.error').on("click", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("error");
});
```

Or you could use toggleClass but all depends on how you want to proceed after the focus.

Comment: <script>
    $("#name").is(":focus"){
        document.getElementById("name").style.border = "none";
    }
</script>

Comment: I tried this but the detectign focus isn't working. without that the border is being disbaled. Any tweak top this with which I can acheive this?